# partial differential equation-exercice

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

let in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the equation 
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial t^2} - \dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$
We put: 
$
\begin{cases}
x=\xi + \eta\\
t=\xi- \eta
\end{cases}
$
and $u(x,t)=\tilde{u}(\xi,\eta)$.
1. How we prove that $\dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{u}}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}(\xi,\eta)=0$?
2. How we deduce that the solution of the differential equation is $u(x,t)= f(x+t)+g(x-t)$?
I'm lost, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it like this: you can treat differential operators with constant coefficients like polynomials. So it boils down to the following computation: $$\frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial \xi} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} u\left(\xi+\eta,\xi - \eta\right) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial t},$$and in the same way $$\frac{\partial \widetilde{u}}{\partial \eta} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}. $$Meaning we have: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}, \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial t},$$and so: \begin{align}  \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} &= \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)u \\ &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}u = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}.\end{align}
Now $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \xi\partial \eta}=0 \implies u(\xi, \eta) = f(\xi) + g(\eta) \implies u(x,t) =f(x+t) + g(x-t).$$We're identifying $u$ with $\widetilde{u}$ all the way.

Comment: please, why we have $$\dfrac{\partial \tilde{u}}{\partial \xi}= \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$? How we justify it?

Comment: Chain rule! ${}{}$

Comment: i think that ou missing 1/2. No?

Comment: Well, $\partial_\xi = \partial_x + \partial_t$ and $\partial_\eta = \partial_x - \partial_t$ implies $\partial_x = (\partial_\xi+\partial_\eta)/2$ and $\partial_t = (\partial_\xi -\partial_\eta)/2$.

Comment: Please, why $\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}=0$ implies that $u(\xi,\eta)= f(\xi)+ g(\eta)$? Who are f and g?

Comment: Just integrate both sides wrt $\xi$ and $\eta $.

Comment: Please, can you explain me how you make this integration to found two functions? Thank you

Comment: You do know that $F'(x) = 0 \implies F(x) = {\rm constant}$, right? The point is that when you integrate wrt to $\xi$, the "constant" is only constant wrt to $\xi$, meaning that it is only a function of $\eta$. The same reasoning applies again when you integrate in $\eta$ later.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't clear. $\dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{u}}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}=0$ implies that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \dfrac{\partial^2 \tilde{u}}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}=0$ and what's the following to obtain $f(\xi)+g(\eta)$? Please.

Comment: $$\partial^2_{\xi \eta}u=0 \implies \partial_\xi u = \widetilde{f}(\xi) \implies u = f(\xi) + g(\eta),$$where $f(\xi) = \int \widetilde{f}(\xi)\,d\xi$. We're not looking at definite integrals.

Comment: i think that there is an mistake. We have:$$\partial^2_{\xi \eta}u=0 => \partial_{\xi,\eta}= f(x,\eta)$$ no?

Comment: No. When you integrate both sides wrt $\eta$, the left side becomes $\partial_\xi u$ and the right side is the integral of $0$ wrt $\eta$, which is $0$ plus a constant (wrt $\eta$). That constant will be a function of $\xi$ **only**.

Comment: in my mind, we have: $$\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}=0 => \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}= C$$ and so $u(\xi,\eta)= C \xi$$ . Can you help me to correct this formula, please

Comment: That $C$ is a function of $\xi$, as I explained above. And in what follows, when you integrate in $\xi$, the other constant will be a function of $\eta$ only. This kind of computation appears a lot when finding potentials for conservative vector fields. I think it would be helpful if you reviewed a few examples of that. Unfortunately English is not my native tongue and so I don't know calculus books in English to reccomend. :(

Comment: Please, can you write me thes last message with using mathematics symbols? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tilde{u}=v$.

$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial t^2} - \dfrac{\partial^2 v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$

Note that:

$$\xi=\frac{x+t}{2}$$
$$\eta=\frac{x-t}{2}$$

Now use chain rule

$$
\dfrac{\partial v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial t} =\dfrac{\partial v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \xi}\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \eta}\dfrac{\partial \eta}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \xi}-\frac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial \eta}
$$

Use chain rule again for

$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial t^2} 
$$

Do the same with

$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 v(\xi,\eta)}{\partial x^2} 
$$

Plug your results into the PDE and check if it is zero.

Answer (score 0):

One must convert the derivative operators first,
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial t} = -u_\xi + u_\eta
\end{align}
and likewise
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x } = u_\xi + u_\eta
\end{align}
where I've used $\xi = x-t$ and $\eta = x+t$ because these coordinates make the work is a bit more clear.  By doing so, you are now looking at this PDE along the characteristics ($\xi$ and $\eta$), which is usually a simplification compared to the normal problem.

Computing the second derivative is straightforward,
\begin{align}
\partial_{tt} = \partial_{\xi\xi} - 2\partial_{\xi\eta} + \partial_{\eta\eta},\\
\partial_{xx} = \partial_{\xi\xi} + 2\partial_{\xi\eta} + \partial_{\eta\eta}.
\end{align}
Upon substitution into the PDE, you get your result,
\begin{equation}
4u_{\xi\eta} = 0.
\end{equation}
What type of function is zero after differentiating with respect to $\xi$ once and w.r.t $\eta$ once? Only a function of the form $u = f(\xi) + g(\eta).$